# expose QVector property to D-Bus

Tags: qt, qt5, dbus, qdbus

I want to have a property like

```
Q_PROPERTY(QVector<QString> persons READ persons CONSTANT)
```

to expose it as D-Bus service. Also the client side need to read it of course.

Problem:

When i do like this and start my service it does not show up in QDbusViewer

Thanks for any help.

Comment: use `QStringList` instead `QVector<QString>`

Comment: Ok that worked. And how about a QVector of my own class object like:
QVector<CData> ?